# How to make a command not run as sudo in script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have a script `install.sh` which contains commands to install packages on ubuntu. For ex:

```
#/bin/bash

sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get updgrade
sudo apt-get install <package>
```

Now there is a command which I want to run without sudo so I'll write without sudo

```
#/bin/bash

sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get updgrade
sudo apt-get install <package>
pcmanfm --set-wallpaper /path to file  <-- I want this to be run without sudo
```

But when I run the script, I do `sudo sh install.sh` which automatically makes all the commands to be executed as sudo. Is there anyway, I can protect `pcmanfm` command to not to run as sudo.

Comment: Try this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25215604/use-sudo-without-password-inside-a-script

Comment: just run the script itself without sudo and you should use `upgrade` ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should execute the script in the following way:

```
./install.sh
```

or

```
sh ./install.sh
```

This will cause that only command which start with `sudo` in the script will run as a root.

Note that the `./` prefix for the `install.sh` means that the `install.sh` from the current directory will be executed.

Comment: Yes but for some reason, I need to use sudo for install.sh

Comment: The script execute `sudo` for the commands inside which requires to be executed by `root`. why do you need to execute the entire script as `root` using `sudo`?